# Complex geometric series proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am interested in trying to prove the following unique result:

Re $\left( \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n e^{inx} \right) = \frac{1 - r\cos(x)}{1 - 2r\cos(x) + r^2} $

$r$ is in the interval ]0,1[. I have tried using the De Moivre theorem with the result of an infinite geometric series but I arrive to having a $\cos(nx)$ in the series, which I am unsure how to solve.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Please show your working

Comment: Hello, I am new to the platform. How can I send you my work? Thanks

Comment: You seem to have started well, as the summation does give "an infinite geometric series" involving $r e^{ix}$.  But $n$, the index of summation, should disappear once you replace that geometric series by its explicit value.  So showing your work (tedious though this is for first time users) is really key to pinning down what help is needed.  (It often occurs that going to the trouble of writing it all out will guide you to your own solution, which is a happy outcome.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$
\Re\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^ne^{inx}
= \Re\sum_{n=0}^\infty(r e^{ix})^n
= \Re \frac{1}{1-re^{ix}}
$

Comment: Hello, I have arrived at that result. I have used Euler's formula to obtain $\frac{1}{1 - rcosx - irsinx}$ of which I have to grab the real part. Is it as simple as $\frac{1}{1 - rcosx}$? If so, I arrive at the result $\frac{1 - rcosx}{1 - 2rcosxsinx + r^2 - r^2 sin^2(x)}$, where I used the double angle formula for sine, where I am still blocked. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Try multiplying the numerator and denominator of $1/(1-re^{ix})$ by the complex conjugate $1-re^{-ix}$ before taking the real part.